# Replace whole numbers with decimal point and zeroes with just the whole number

Tags: c#, regex, parsing

I turn to a WCF service and receive from it a string which contains numeric values combined with words.

The point is that I have a requirement to display these sentences on the screen in the following manner:

Instead of:

```
Reduction of 10.00% in first half of year and 13.32% in second half.
```

I want to display:

```
Reduction of 10% in first half of year and 13.32% in second half.
```

In other words: each whole number I get from the service has two digits after the decimal point, and I need to replace it with just the whole number (with no zeroes and no decimal point)

I wonder what is the most efficient way to do that?

Comment: round it off then substring?

Comment: `string result = text.Replace(".00%", "%").Replace(".00 ", " ");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need something like this,

```
(\d+)\.00
```

Replacement string:

```
$1
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/lD1wC7/9)

Comment: The trailing `(%)?` and `$2` are pointless here (although the leading `(\d+)` and `$1` is a nice touch).

Comment: @Rawling op said "the numeric values might no be followed by a % mark"

Comment: Yes, but you're saying "if you find a '%' replace it with a '%', otherwise don't". You'd get the exact same effect without it.

Comment: More like this: http://regex101.com/r/lD1wC7/9 Remove the `(%)?` and the `\2` and you get the exact same result as with them.

Comment: Thanks, Avinash.
var fixedRate = Regex.Replace(rate, @"(\d+)\.00", @"$1");
did the trick.
And thanks for letting me know about: Regex101.com...AWESOME site.

Answer (score 2):

you want `.00%` to be replaced by `%`.

Then just do it.

Comment: Actually I want to replace .00 with empty string (the numeric values might no be followed by a % mark).
Should I use a regex or just parse the string char by char?
A little more info would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: @DimaK, you can use regex like this subsstitute `.00` with blank. A regex as simple as this wont affect the performance much.. so chill and use regex

Answer (score -1):

I think str = Regex.Replace(str,"\.[0-9][0-9]",String.Empty,RegexOptions.None); will help you.

To explain what I do here:
In this case "str" is your inputString and will be replaced with the result of the Regex.Replace method. 
"\.[0-9][0-9]" is the pattern to be replaced. In this case a "." followed by two digits. 
I use String.Empty as replacement string because you just want to cut the pattern off.
No regularexpression options are needed. Therefore the last parameter is RegexOptions.None.